# Simplify form of mySql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to simply following SQL query.
Is there any way to get it??

```
select * 
  from product a 
  where a.brand_id 
    in (select ib.brand_id from 
      SUBSCRIBED_CHANNEL ia inner join product ib 
      where ia.product_id=ib.product_id and ia.user_id=3)
    and a.product_id not in (select ib.product_id from SUBSCRIBED_CHANNEL ia 
    inner join product ib where ia.product_id=ib.product_id and ia.user_id=3)
```

Edited:
four table:

product (PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_ID, BRAND_ID)
SUBSCRIBED_CHANNEL (USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID) 
brand (BRAND_NAME, BRAND_ID)
user (..., user_id)

product to brand -> many to one
product to user -> many to many
subscribed_channel -> middle table

I need to get products that are not subscribed by user. 
for example: if Nike Brand has product xx, yy and zz
and if user is only subscribed to xx then my query has to give only yy, zz as a result.

Comment: post an [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) or, if this is part of stored procedure, [analyse()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html) and we'll see.

Comment: read up on how to do joins. all those in and not in would probably perform like dog doo doo

Comment: Can you describe what this query is trying to do?  I think there is an easier way to express it.  However, reading it, I get pretty lost in how many brands are on a product or in subscribed channel and so on.

Comment: I have edited further information

Comment: select ib.brand_id from SUBSCRIBED_CHANNEL ia inner join product ib where ia.product_id=ib.product_id and ia.user_id=3 
called two times, instead i wanted to call one time. Is there any possible way to do that??

Comment: @Nihanth: You have to access product twice - once to determine which brand(s) correspond to the user's subscribed channels, once to retrieve all products for those brands - but there is a way to access subscribed_channel only once; I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Amended) Try:

```
select distinct a.* 
from product a
join product b on a.brand_id = b.brand_id 
join subscribed_channel i on b.product_id = i.product_id and i.user_id=3
left join subscribed_channel n on a.product_id = n.product_id and n.user_id=3
where n.product_id is null
```

Alternatively:

```
select a.* 
from product a
join product b on a.brand_id = b.brand_id 
join subscribed_channel i on b.product_id = i.product_id and i.user_id=3
group by a.product_id
having sum(case when a.product_id = b.product_id then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: @Nihanth: Can you clarify that last comment? This answer *should* replicate the functionality of your existing query using only joins (instead of subqueries); it *may* perform better than your existing query. It's up to you to confirm that (a) you are happy that it does match functionality, and (b) it does perform better - it could conceivably perform worse (due to the join of product to product on brand_id).

Comment: Thanks Mark... i chose second ans, may i know why my query is bad in performance wise?

Comment: @Nihanth: I don't know how your original query performed, or how much the alternative improved on it, so I don't know how they compare. Your existing query had two sub-queries, each of which (I think) *may* have been evaluated for each row of product, whereas the modified queries should have only been accessing each table once per alias; inspecting the query plans for each query should provide further insight.

Comment: I agree with your point, and i wanted to know why you have used JOIN instead of INNER JOIN? both give same ans

Comment: @Nihanth: JOIN is INNER JOIN - the `INNER` keyword is optional. Other forms of join - CROSS, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, FULL OUTER - require additional keywords to indicate that they are not INNER joins.